# SOCAT - Forwarding TCP packets to UDP

Tags: sockets, networking, udp, port, socat

I have an application that sends simple data over TCP (simple, no auth) and another application that must receive it. The only allowed connection between the two is UDP.

On the receiving side, I have SOCAT listening for incoming UDP packets and forwarding them via a TCP connection to the computer that hosts the software.

> socat UDP4-LISTEN:5000, fork TCP-CONNECT:192.168.1.5:5001

On the sending side, I can send test data via

> socat UDP4-connect 192.168.1.1:5000

There is a firewall in the way and I have no control over it which is why UDP is my only option. The firewall allows UDP out from the sender and UDP in to the receiver.

What I don't know is how to take a TCP connection on the sender and forward its output via UDP. And I don't know if this is the best way or if it will work at all.

Thank you

Comment: The way to do that is use a tunnel that uses UDP as the tunnel protocol, and you tunnel the TCP _segments_ (not packets) inside UDP _datagrams_ (not packets). This is not actually a programming question, it is a network question.

Comment: Can you point me in the right direction to do that? I have access to SOCAT and I can use dd-wrt at both ends if needed. Keeping in mind, I can only receive UDP. The system can not respond back through which means a TCP handshake couldn't happen as I understand the tunnel.

Comment: This is really not a programming question, so you are asking on the wrong SE site. Most SE site do not allow recommendations for off-site resources or products. For example, the [help/on-topic] says: "_Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it._"

Comment: Similar question/posts which include the relevant part to forward tcp as udp see [here](https://superuser.com/questions/53103/udp-traffic-through-ssh-tunnel) or [here](https://itecnote.com/tecnote/forward-udp-with-ssh-tunnel-using-socat-and-putty/). Basically something like `socat tcp4-listen:12345,reuseaddr,fork,bind=127.0.0.1 UDP:ip:port`